# Mysql: How to fetch database data in different variables

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT description FROM `tbl_news` where `flag`=1 and `show_at`='notice_board'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0)
  {
   $i=1;
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
   {
?>
    <br/>
    <img src="images1/left_nav_symbol.png" alt="" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font color="#000000">
    <?php echo $row['description'];?> <img src="images1/new1.GIF" alt=""/>
    </font>
    <?php
    $i=$i+1;    
   }    
 }
 else
 { 
   echo "No records found.";
 }
```

This is my code. I want to fetch values of column `description` by the latest value, show it by highlighting or set a new button image to it.
Is there any solution for it?

Comment: And how you know it is latest ? By `id` column or you have `date` column something ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of `$i` here?

Comment: when echo $row['description']; this code prints data then it shows latest record first then remaining and only those record which has flag 1

Answer (score 0):

For latest value , you can use `MAX`

```
MAX(description) in select query
```

Comment: yes i got latest value from select MAX(description) and i show it in highlight now i want all remaining data in simple format below that latest value.

Answer (score 0):

The table should have an `auto_increment` ID or a datetime field (maybe with the default value `NOW()`), indicating when the rows were inserted.

Using this field you can order the results of the query like:

```
SELECT description FROM `tbl_news` where `flag`=1 and `show_at`='notice_board' ORDER BY `stored_at` DESC
```